dumbphone/ featurephone that can be used to place and receive tethered calls (connected to router/ computer)
Ahoj,
my daily mobile phone is a Microsoft Nokia 515.
However, I am now searching for a dumbphone or featurephone with one special functionality (that is not easy to internet-search for): That calls can be placed from a router or Computer through the phone, connected via USB or Bluetooth.
Like that some LTE USB sticks can also be used for making calls I want to use the phone.
Use case: When at home I want to connect it to my telephony system (ideally Fritz!Box, but I also could hack something using Asterisk on OpenWrt or so) to use my desk phone to make and receive calls via my mobile phone line.
And when I go, I just want to pick the phone and take it with me.
The Nokia 515 cannot do it.
Any recommendations?
I do not want to take the very old Siemens phones since they do not support multipart SMS text messages.
I would prefer if the phone also has a LED torch and FM radio and a very simple camera, but not necessary.
It does not need something new. It can be an old(er) device, and used one is perfectly fine.
Regards!

Many countries have killed off 2 and even 3G support, so including what band support your country supports may be useful

Sounds like you want a phone that can do SIP. There are apps for more modern phones (e.g. running Android) like "ZoiPer" you can use to connect to your Fritz!Box and do landline calls through your router like that.
I don't think any "feature phones" would support that though and I'm not sure doing that over USB or Bluetooth is even an option. Perhaps using MicroSIP on the PC and a phone that can act as a headset over USB / Bluetooth would work?

@towe, I definitely do not want a Smartphone. And non-smartphones that can do SIP are quite -- rare. But if there is any, that has good usability (not like the Pirelli DP-L10), then I could accept that, too.

@JourneymanGeek, it is in Germany, 2G still here. But Having 4G/Voice and SMS over LTE is definitely a nice option.

@towe: Addendum: And then the phone still needs to support to route an outgoing call, that it receives via SIP, via GSM and the other way round to route the receiving GSM call via SIP.
